# AutoMapper configuration. ViewModel to DomainModel

Tags: c#

I need litle help with mapping my viewmodel to domain model.

View model:

```
public class CampaignViewModel
{
    public CampaignVM Campaign { get; set; }
    public DiscountVM Discount { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Model:

```
 public class Campaign : Entity
{
    public Campaign();

    public Discount Discount { get; set; }
    // other properties 
}
```

And how I can handle that via automapper? 
I tried:

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CampaignViewModel, Campaign>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Campaign)));
```

But how to map the other classes? Like DiscountVM => Discount...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>cfg.CreateMap()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Campaign, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Campaign)))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Discount , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Discount )));
var result=Mapper.Map();
```

or simply just this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>cfg.CreateMap());
var result=Mapper.Map();
```

because the properties of both the source and the destination classes have the same name. Therefore, they will be mapped automatically. you just have to write (.ForMember) part for properties with different names.